# webcam not working in 13.04

Tags: webcam

I'm running 13.04 (64-bit version) but my webcam (Microsoft Lifecam NX-3000) stopped working when I upgraded. I downloaded the 32-bit drivers which fixed it for a while but now it's not recognised in Skype, Cheese or VLC.

Here's the output of *lsusb*:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:0721 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam NX-3000 (UVC-compliant)
```

And here's *dmesg | grep uvcvideo*:

```
[   16.552513] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Microsoft LifeCam NX-3000 (045e:0721)
[   16.553854] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[   16.554225] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
[   16.554234] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
[   16.554996] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Answer (score 2):

I got mine working as follows in (13.10):

```
echo 'options uvcvideo quirks=0x100' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/uvcvideo.conf
```

[www.linux-hardware-guide.com](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-10-16-microsoft-lifecam-nx-3000-usb-webcam)

Comment: Thanks, this worked with my USB microscope on Ubuntu 16.04. I ran your command, followed by:
```sudo rmmod uvcvideo; sudo modprobe uvcvideo```

Answer (score 0):

please reload the uvcvideo again and look if makes a different:

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

Regards, Torsten

Comment: Thanks Torsten, I've tried this but I still get similar results from dmesg (as above but repeated three times). I have managed to get the camera to work however by simply using a different usb port - I'll see if it fixes it permanently.

Comment: Looks like this was a temporary fix. I had to restart and it's not working again. At startup I get an error message saying:
[   14.350290] uvcvideo: Failed to query .(129) UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26)
[   14.350298] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).

I'd be very grateful for any ideas on how I might solve this?

Andy